# Carbon - disable the default year setting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

I am trying to build a search functionality with an input text field that accepts any string.

Carbon will try to parse the user input, and it is enclosed in a try catch statement.

I only want to get the specific input by user, example when he only enters "dec 25", year must be null. Same goes for the day ("jan 1998"). Should the user not included the month, the Carbon will throw an exception.

as we all know, Carbon is setting the default year by the current year when we parse a date without specifying a year.

Is it possible to disable the "setting the default year" behavior when parsing a date?

Example

```
$myDate = Carbon::parse('dec 25');
```

myDate must return null when getting the year property.

```
$myDate->year; // MUST RETURN NULL;
```

My best case scenario, checks if the user supplied day or year is the same as today: (looks something like this)

```
if ($searchRecordArray['type'][$i] === "dategrad") {
    $q->where(function ($subQuery) use ($searchValueExploded) {
        foreach ($searchValueExploded as $value) {
            $searchDate = Carbon::parse($value);
            // dd([$searchDate->month, $searchDate->day, $searchDate->year]);
            $subQuery->orWhere(function ($subDateQuery) use ($searchDate) {
                $subDateQuery->whereMonth("date_grad", $searchDate->month);
                if ($searchDate->year !== Carbon::now()->year) {
                    if ($searchDate->day === Carbon::now()->day) {
                        $subDateQuery->whereYear("date_grad", $searchDate->year);
                    } else if ($searchDate->day !== Carbon::now()->day) {
                        $subDateQuery->whereDay("date_grad", $searchDate->day);
                        $subDateQuery->whereYear("date_grad", $searchDate->year);
                    }
                } else if ($searchDate->year === Carbon::now()->year) {
                    if ($searchDate->day === Carbon::now()->day) {

                    } else if ($searchDate->day !== Carbon::now()->day) {
                        $subDateQuery->whereDay("date_grad", $searchDate->day);
                        $subDateQuery->whereYear("date_grad", $searchDate->year);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: if you don't want to set year then why are u trying to get it ?

Comment: I am creating a search function that accepts a keyword that would be parsed by Carbon. It is enclosed in a try- catch if Carbon fails

Comment: If the user passed a string keyword wtihout a year, the year must be null, which is checked. If the year is null, Laravel will not include a whereYear query.

Comment: And by default, it will supply a default year (the current year). Same goes if you didn't supply a day.

Comment: i think that's not possible, a `Carbon` object is a Date Time object, it should have a day, month and a year. update your question to provide a context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: try changing the user's way of input. you can have three dropdowns for each date field (month, day, year) and based from there, build your query. I believe that is more easier to implement.